# Skype alternative

Tags: skype

My son is to follow his school lessons from the computor through a chat client. He is advised to use Skype for this. His teacher will be using Skype on Windows.

What is the best option which would give all the features of Skype (audio, video, file transfer etc..)?

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4

Answer (score 2):

Use Skype. It's available in the Ubuntu software centre!

[image]

Comment: I've added the image from UBC to aid your answer. - You just beat me to it!

Comment: That looks much better ;)

Comment: Hi.
I just tried to install Skype but it said that this app can access to all personal files and system resources. What does this mean? Does this means that somehow Skype can copy, delete or open my personal files?

Comment: I think it is just referring to your camera and microphone, which it needs to access in order to work! It's very unlikely that it would  access personal files as it's a Micosoft product and they have to comply with data protection regulations.